# Logback logging class consistency

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I've been using Log4j informally for a while and am now switching to Logback.  I've grown used to using [Spiffy](http://spiffyframework.sourceforge.net/) to [ensure my logging class is consistent](http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/getting_log4j_loggers.html).

i.e. instead of

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( Foo.class );
```

or

```
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( this.getClass() );
```

I do

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerHelper.getLogger();
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Logback?  I don't know how Spiffy does what it does at this stage, I just use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't normally use logback directly, but via [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).  This is how it's used:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class A
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);

    public void method1()
    {
        logger.info("Hello world");
        ....
    }
}
```

Then during deployment you can put the logback jars and configuration into your classpath in order to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Spiffy's LoggerHelper uses the [Throwable.getStackTrace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) method. Unfortunately, this method is not 100% reliable. From the javadocs:

> Some virtual machines may, under some
>   circumstances, omit one or more stack
>   frames from the stack trace.

In other words, Spiffy's LoggerHelper may return incorrectly named loggers. If this happens, the occurrence will be very difficult to debug.